# custom button with different states in ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am creating a button component that has a loading component when clicked [inspired by this fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewDryga/GY6LC/).

The following handlebars shows the component:

```
{{#if 'hasSpinner'}}
    <span class="spinner fa-spin icon-refresh"></span>
{{/if}}
{{#if 'hasFailureCross'}}
    <span class="failure-cross glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
{{/if}}
{{#if 'hasSuccessTick'}}
    <span class="success-tick glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
{{/if}}
{{buttonText}}
```

and this is the Component Class:

```
// shows a button with a spinner
App.AppButtonProgressComponent = Em.Component.extend({
    //defaults
    buttonType: 'btn-default',

    //you can choose whether or not to have the following elements
    hasSpinner: true,
    hasFailureCross: false,
    hasSuccessCross: false,

    //when these are active, the css kicks in and adds the icons to the button
    spinner: false,
    failureCross: false,
    successTick: false,

    actions: {
        click: function() {
            this.set('spinner', true);
            this.sendAction();
        },
        showFailure: function() {
            console.log('should show cross or something');
            this.set('spinner', false);
            this.set('failureCross', true);
        },
        showSuccess: function() {
            console.log('should show success');
            this.set('spinner', false);
            this.set('successTick', true);
        },
        reset: function() {
            this.set('spinner', false);
            this.set('successTick', false);
            this.set('failureCross', false);
        }
    },
    tagName: 'button',
    classNames: ['btn'],
    classNameBindings: ['buttonType', 'spinner', 'failureCross', 'successTick']
});
```

Handling the state therefore is a matter of implementing a state variable in the parent view controller. how would i call each of these functions from outside the component? say if the button was clicked, setting the spinner to true and causing the loading symbol, if the request that get's bubbled out to the controller fails or succeeds, how would i call the component's `showSuccess` or `showFailure` method.

Am i understanding components incorrectly? is there a better way to acheive this?

**UPDATE:** I'm still working on the component and intend to release the tested and finished element to the public.

Answer (score 1):

Components are one way devices.  That being said, you can send arguments with your `sendAction` and rely on the action to make the callbacks.  That puts the responsibility on the parent action, but it allows you to interact with your component when appropriate.

I've created a dummied down version of what you were created, and modified a few things just to show the concept.

```
    showFailure: function() {
        console.log('should show cross or something');
        this.set('spinner', false);

        this.set('failureCross', true);
    },
    showSuccess: function() {
        console.log('should show success');
        this.set('spinner', false);
        this.set('successTick', true);
    },
    reset: function() {
        this.set('spinner', false);
        this.set('successTick', false);
        this.set('failureCross', false);
    },
    actions:{
      click: function() {
        var self = this;
          this.set('spinner', true);

        this.sendAction('action', 
            function(){ self.showFailure(); },
            function(){ self.showSuccess(); },
            function(){ self.reset(); }
                       );
    }
```

And then in the parent action that recieves the callbacks

```
actions:{
    doit: function(failure, success, reset){
      Ember.run.later(function(){
         // call reject 1 second later for visual effects
         // as if we made a call to the server
         failure();
      }, 1000);
    }
  }
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qumupaxa/1/edit